# If a linear transformation $T$ has $z^n$ as the minimal polynomial, there is a vector $v$ such that $v, Tv,\dots, T^{n-1}v$ are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $T: V \to V$ with the minimal polynomial $z^n$. Prove that there's a vector $v$ such that $v, Tv, T^2v, ..., T^{n-1}v$ are linearly independent.

The way I did it orginally was not allowed. No Jordan Forms are allowed because we did not cover them this semester. I asked my professor for a hint and all he said was we need to use induction. I wish I had something to work with, but I'm so  lost. It's my last problem. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: if such a $v$ exists, it can't be in in $\ker(T^{n-1})$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $z^n$ is the *minimal* polynomial, we have $T^{n-1}\neq 0$ and hence $\exists v\in V$ such that $T^{n-1}v\neq 0$. Suppose
$$a_0v+a_1Tv+\cdots +a_{n-1}T^{n-1}v=0.$$
Applying $T^{n-1}$ on both sides yields $a_0T^{n-1}v=0$ and hence $a_0=0$. Now,
$$a_1Tv+a_2T^2v+\cdots +a_{n-1}T^{n-1}v=0$$
and applying $T^{n-2}$ gives $a_1=0$. Now, you should be able to see how to use induction.

Comment: Thank you! So to be sure, when a transformation is done on vector v n times it becomes 0? Does that come from the definition of minimum polynomial?

Comment: Yes, the fact that $z^n$ is the minimal polynomial says that $T^n=0$, i.e. $T^nu=0$ for all $u\in V$.

Comment: You're awesome! Thank you so much!